# VsSolutionBuildManager: How to enable the build while debugging?

Tags: c#, .net, build

We implement the build and debug features in our product. When user make some change, user could require validate. We use the VS buildmanager service to perform the validation:

```
IVsSolutionBuildManager2 buildManager = this.project.GetService(typeof(SVsSolutionBuildManager)) as IVsSolutionBuildManager2;
int result = buildManager.StartUpdateSpecificProjectConfigurations(
    1,
    new IVsProjectCfg[] { projectCfg },
    new uint[] { 0 },
    new uint[] { VSConstants.VS_BUILDABLEPROJECTCFGOPTS_BUILD_SELECTION_ONLY },
    new uint[] { 0 },
    (uint)VSSOLNBUILDUPDATEFLAGS.SBF_OPERATION_BUILD,
    0);
```

And we override the BuildableProjectConfig.StartBuild method, put the validation logic in it.

When user invokes the validation during debug, StartUpdateSpecificProjectConfigurations will pop up a dialog to ask whether to stop the debug; it will exit unless you choose stop debugging.

Now we want to enable the validation during debug session, just like the “Edit and run”. How to make the StartUpdateSpecificProjectConfigurations continue while debug doesn’t stop?